# Why Is Delete Rows Method Deleting an Entire Table?

Tags: javascript

I have written a method that is supposed to delete a row based on what checkbox is selected on submit using Javascript.

I am using the library method deleteRow to delete the row once I have determined the checkbox for that row is checked. However, 2 things happen. If the first row is selected it deletes the whole table. If it is any other checkbox, it validates the checkbox is checked, but it does nothing.

```
  function deleteRows(){
     var objTable = document.getElementById('breakTable');
    var checkBoxes = objTable.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    

        for(var i=0; i<checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        alert("in for");
            if(checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            alert("in if 2");
                objTable.deleteRow(1);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }

                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what library includes the deleteRow method? So I am unsure if checkboxes.deleteRow(1) is the right syntax. Assuming it is, you need to  use checkBoxes[i].deleteRow(1) to delete a particular row. Otherwise, deleteRow will apply to the whole collection of checkboxes and delete all row.

The above change will work if only one checkbox is selected. It will not work as expected with multiple checkboxes, as you are also decreasing the value of i (i--) in the loop. This will mess up the index of checkboxes collection.

Comment: It should actually be objTable.deleteRow(i), but here is the library.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/deleteRow